# RuntimeError: shape '[128, -1, 10]' is invalid for input of size 2048

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, time-series, autoencoder, transformer-model

Currently I process with the x_train data with the size of (7304,20) and y_train of (7304,3) . After loading through data loader method and passing its through the model, I have the error as the mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied with each other. Here is some information about my model:

```
Net(
(pos): PositionalEncoding()
(cell): TransformerEncoder(
(layers): ModuleList(
  (0-2): 3 x TransformerEncoderLayer(
    (self_attn): MultiheadAttention(
      (out_proj): NonDynamicallyQuantizableLinear(in_features=10, out_features=10, bias=True)
    )
    (linear1): Linear(in_features=10, out_features=64, bias=True)
    (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
    (linear2): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=10, bias=True)
    (norm1): LayerNorm((10,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
    (norm2): LayerNorm((10,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
    (dropout1): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
    (dropout2): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
  )
  )
   )
 (linear): Linear(in_features=10, out_features=1, bias=True)
(autoencoder): Autoencoder(
(fc1): Linear(in_features=20, out_features=16, bias=True)
(fc2): Linear(in_features=16, out_features=20, bias=True)
 )
 )
```

I intend to build an AE-Transformer model but the error occurs as it requires the input of 2048 instead of shape '[128, -1, 10]'. For more detail, here is my model:

```
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_dim,embed_dim, noise_level):
    super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
    self.input_size, self.hidden_dim, self.noise_level = input_size, embed_dim,noise_level
    self.embed_dim = embed_dim
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.input_size, self.hidden_dim)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.input_size)
    
def encoder(self,x):
    x = self.fc1(x)
    h1 = F.relu(x)
    return h1

def mask(self,x):
    corrupted_x = x + self.noise_level + torch.randn_like(x)   # randn_like  Initializes a tensor where all the elements are sampled from a normal distribution.
    return corrupted_x

def decoder(self, x):
    h2 = self.fc2(x)
    return h2

def forward (self, x):
    out = self.mask(x) # Adding noise to feed the network
    encoder = self.encoder(out)
    decoder = self.decoder(encoder)
    return encoder, decoder 

## Transformer 
### Positional encoding
    class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,d_model, dropout=0.0,max_len=16):
        super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
        pe = torch.zeros(max_len,d_model)
        position = torch.arange(0,max_len, dtype = torch.float).unsqueeze(1)
        
        div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0,d_model,2).float()*(-math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
        
        pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)

        pe = pe.unsqueeze(0).transpose(0, 1)

        self.register_buffer('pe', pe)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = x + self.pe[:x.size(1), :].squeeze(1)
        return x
    
    Class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,feature_size,num_layers,n_head,dropout,noise_level,embed_dim):
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.embed_dim = embed_dim
        self.hidden_dim = 4*embed_dim
        self.auto_hidden = int(feature_size / 2)
        input_size = self.auto_hidden
        self.pos = PositionalEncoding(d_model=input_size, max_len=input_size)
        encoder_layers = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=input_size, nhead=n_head, dim_feedforward=self.hidden_dim, dropout=dropout)
        self.cell = nn.TransformerEncoder(encoder_layers,num_layers=num_layers)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(input_size,1)
        self.autoencoder = Autoencoder(input_size = feature_size, hidden_dim = self.auto_hidden,embed_dim = embed_dim, noise_level=noise_level)
          
    def forward(self,x):
        batch_size, feature_num, feature_size = x.shape
        encode, decode = self.autoencoder(x.view(batch_size,-1).float()) # Equals batch_size * seq_len
        out = encode.reshape(batch_size, -1, self.auto_hidden)
        out = self.pos(out)
        out = out.reshape(1,batch_size,-1)  #(1,batch_size,feature_size)
        out = self.cell(out)
        out = out.reshape(batch_size,-1)
        out = self.linear(out)
        
        return out, decode
```

And here is further detail of the error. Please see the [Shape error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQLyt.png).

As a newbie so I find it's a little bit confusing when building this deep learning model. So can someone explain to me how to solve this problem ?